# Не могу достать значение с многомерного массива PHP

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой массив $rsCategory. В [0]  идут значения и последнее значение еще один массив [children] в котором есть еще 2 массива и мне надо вытянуть из них parent_id
Вот что я пытаюсь сделать :

```
if ($rsCategory['children']['parent_id'] == 1){
        echo "helo world ";
    }
```

обращаюсь к массиву (в данном примере только к первому элементу ), в нем ищу ключ [children] и в нем с всех дочерних массивов  достаю [parent_id] и если он равен 1 то выводит сообщение

Ну у меня в итоге на моём  учебном сайте при клике на Телефоны самсунг или Телефоны епл должно выводится helo world

Comment: " В [0] идут значения ". Ну и где здесь обращение к 0?

Comment: @Ипатьев ну к примеру у меня будет несколько ключей [1] [2] [3] то я же не буду для каждого отдельно писать обращение.Разве оно автоматом не проходится по каждому ключу?

Comment: Нет, никаким "автоматом" программы ничего не делают. Они делают только то, что написал программист. Если надо, чтобы "оно" проходилось, то это надо написать.

Answer (score 0):

Вы пропускаете целые уровни в ассоциативном массиве. Попробуйте так

```
if ($rsCategory[0]['children'][0]['parent_id'] == 1){
        echo "helo world ";
    }
```

Если для всех, тогда нужно пройтись циклом:

```
foreach ($rsCategory as $category) {
    foreach ($category['children'] as $child) {
        if ($child['parent_id'] == 1) {
            echo $child['id'] . ' - ' . $child['name'] . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы упростить решение вашей задачи "Ну у меня в итоге на моём учебном сайте при клике на Телефоны самсунг или Телефоны епл должно выводится helo world" скорее всего можно сделать обычный массив типа:

```
$rsCategory = [
    $catID1 => [
      'id' => $catID1, 
      'parent_id' => $parentID, 
      'name' => $categoryName2, 
      'level' => $level //если нужно
     ], 

    $catID2 => [
      'id' => $catID2, 
      'parent_id' => $parentID, 
      'name' => $categoryName2, 
      'level' => $level //если нужно
     ],
     .....
]
```

тогда при клике вы получаете $catID нужной категории и проверяете

```
if ($rsCategory[$catID]['parent_id'] == 1) {
   echo "helo world ";
}
```

Comment: Увы вы обратились здесь только к первым ключам а мне надо что бы в [children] обращалось и к первому массиву и к второму (ну их там может быть сколько угодно).Есть альтернативный способ что бы каждый раз не обращаться к каждому ключу отдельно?

Comment: @ZELIBOBA пройдитесь по массиву через foreach

Answer (score 0):

Используйте вложенные циклы:

```
$rsCategory = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'parent_id' => 0,
        'name' => 'Телефони',
        'children' => [
            [
                'id' => 3,
                'parent_id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Телефони Samsung'
            ],
            [
                'id' => 4,
                'parent_id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Телефони Aple'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];


foreach ($rsCategory as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr['children'] as $arr_2) {
        if ($arr_2['parent_id'] == 1) {
            echo $arr_2['name'] . "\n";
        }
    }
}

/* Результат:
Телефони Samsung
Телефони Aple
*/
```